# Changing height after dragging and dropping

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

All,

I have a circle that I drag and drop from the upper div to the bottom div.  Please see fiddle.  After I click the circle in the bottom I then try to change the height with the input button.  The input button is between the top and bottom div and uses incremental values of 5.

However, my event handler doesn't change the height value after incrementing from 5 to 10.

My goal is to allow changing of a height especially after I dropped a circle in the bottom and div and after selecting the circle to simulate activation.

Is there something wrong with how I'm trying to associate the event handler to the circle and the input button?

https://jsfiddle.net/mdevera/ff1bfpsd/

```
destinationContainer.addEventListener("click", change);

function change(event) {
  activeShape = event.srcElement;
}

function changeHeight(event) {
  //var height = (parseInt(activeShape.clientHeight, 10) +        parseInt(event.target.value, 10)) + "px";
  activeShape.style.height = event.target.value + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `click` event listener for the `#destination` element only calls the `change` function when it is clicked. In other words, the `change` function isn't fired when you drag/drop the element since there aren't any click events fired. As a result, the `activeShape` variable defined in the `change` function doesn't point to an element since the `change` function is never called.

Another approach would be to select the last child element of the `#destination` element using the [`:last-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child). The last child is always the last element appended which means that you would always target the most recently dropped element when changing the height.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o43ydpfv/)

```
function changeHeight(event) {
  var activeShape = destinationContainer.querySelector(':last-child');

  if (activeShape !== null) {
    activeShape.style.height = event.target.value + "px";
  }
}
```

---

After reading your comment:

In addition to the changes above, it also seems like you are looking for the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) rather than the `change` event. The `input` event is fired fired synchronously when the value of the element is changed, whereas the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) is fired on `blur` (which is when focus is removed from that field).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tL5n8f69/)

```
var destinationContainer = document.querySelector("#destination");
var input = document.querySelector('#height-input');

input.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  var activeShape = destinationContainer.querySelector(':last-child');

  if (activeShape !== null) {
    activeShape.style.height = event.target.value + "px";
  }
});
```

Comment: Josh, thank you so much for the quick response!  However, the height of the circle still does not change after incrementing the input from 5 to 10 to 15....etc.  Especially when trying to target the last-child.  What is weird is that after you do change the incremental value then hover over the bottom div then the circle height changes.

Comment: @M_devera - Then it seems like you want the `input` event. I updated my answer, here is an updated example -> https://jsfiddle.net/tL5n8f69/

Answer (score 0):

It looks unusual, but you should move out of input after changes made or use keys up/down to "catch up" input changes. In general it's some kind of `onblur` needed. In modern browser `oninput` event is preferable one for such cases.

- `onchange` - only after focus out
- `oninput` - the same as onchange but do not need blur focus
- `onpropertychange` -

Just change `onchange` in your HTML to `oninput` and your problem will be resolved.